# VSCode GitHub remote repository with Python Notebook Local Kernel

Tags: python, github, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, remote-repository

Has anyone managed to run an ipynb Python notebook using a local kernel but connecting to a remote GitHub repository using the GitHub Repositories extenstion.

I can open the ipynb file directly from the GitHub repo but cannot connect to a kernel because it doesn't seem to find the local cached version of the notebook to run.

Error message:

```
[C 10:22:20.876 NotebookApp] Bad config encountered during initialization: No such notebook dir: ''/githubuser/reponame''
```

Using:
MacOS

VSC 1.66

GitHub Repositories extension v0.28.0

Tried multiple Python kernels.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am using windows, and it works well on my side. I think this extension works well with the local python environment.

The problem you have run across looks like the problem of jupyter configuration. You can execute `jupyter --paths` to get the jupyter configuration path. It should be  `“/Users/UserName/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py”` on the MacOs. You can refer to [here](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html) for the details of `jupyter_notebook_config.py`.

Then you need to modify `c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir =` to a existing path or just comment it.

Comment: Thanks. My kernel is correctly detected. The issue is that it's running it with --notebook-dir="/githubuser/reponame", which doesn't exist. So it looks like VSC isn't correctly caching the file from github locally and then referring to that when the kernel is run.